A girl building card towers in her room
The only scene that I can remember from this movie is about a girl building playing card towers in her room and I think she has some kind of autism. I'm not sure if she has "telekinetic powers", but I might have mistaken that to another movie. It's probably more than 10 years old.

Country\language? Year?

I can't remember I was a child, probably more than 10 years ago.

OK, added and posted a possible match.

Possibly House of Cards with Kathleen Turner and Tommy Lee Jones from 1993:

When Ruth Matthews's husband is killed in a fall at an archaeological dig, her daughter Sally handles her father's death in a very odd manner. As Sally's condition worsens, Ruth takes her to see Jake, an expert in childhood autism. Jake attempts to bring Sally out of her mental disarray through traditional therapy methods, but Ruth takes a different route. She risks her own sanity by attempting to enter her daughter's mind and make sense of the seemingly bizarre things that Sally does, including building a wondrous house of cards. 

Here's the trailer, where that house of cards figures prominently:



